# Angularjs JSONP not working

Tags: angularjs, jsonp

I might be missing something here but I can't make this JSONP request work, here is the code:

```
var url =  'http://' + server + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
       console.log('success');
    })
    .error(function () {
      console.log('error')
    });
```

The request fires ok and I am getting the response (with header Content-Type:application/json) in this format:

```
    [{"id": "1", "name": "John Doe"},
     {"id": "2", "name": "Lorem ipsum"},
     {"id": "3", "name": "Lorem ipsum"}]
```

Can you see anything wrong? Maybe the format I should return from the server is not right?
Angular fires the error callback without any error message besides the one I set ('error').

Comment: Can you post a Plunker?

Comment: what response do you see in fiddler or firebug

Comment: The response does not look right, it should be a function call to the callback function specified by the request

Comment: @joakimbl is correct. That's not JSONP, that's just JSON. Your response should be a javascript file with the object literal returned inside of a function named after the callback you passed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) requires you do wrap your data into a JavaScript function call. So technically you return a JavaScript file and not a Json file.

The data returned from server should similar to this:

```
// the name should match the one you add to the url
JSON_CALLBACK([
    {"id": "1", "name": "John Doe"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Lorem ipsum"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "Lorem ipsum"}
]);
```

**Edit**: If some one else stumbles across problems with angular's JSONP please also read [this answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16352746/45786), it contains usefull informations about how angular handles the actual callback function.

Comment: Solved! Thanks. TheHippo if you could edit your answer to include what @Gloopy commented: "Angular's $http.jsonp converts the request querystring parameter from callback=JSON_CALLBACK to callback=angular.callbacks._0", so the response is not exactly JSON_CALLBACK() but 

angular.callbacks._0([
 {"id":"1", "name":"John Doe"},
 {"id":"2", "name":"Lorem ipsum"}]); 

If there is more than one request the second jsonp convert the request querystring callback=JSON_CALLBACK to angular.callbacks._1 and so forth, so in my case (PHP server) I am using $_GET['callback']to get the right callback name.

Answer (score 30):

@TheHippo is correct the data should not just be a plain json response. [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FDH8D/) of a JSONP request against a youtube endpoint in AngularJS.

A couple of things to note in this example:

- Angular's [$http.jsonp](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#jsonp) converts the request querystring parameter from `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to `callback=angular.callbacks._0`.
- When calling the youtube endpoint I needed to specify to the service that this is a JSONP request by using `alt=json-in-script` instead of `alt=json` in the querystring. This was found in their [documentation.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters)
- Compare the results of [this url](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/orbitalofficial/uploads?alt=json) to [this one](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/orbitalofficial/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=JSON_CALLBACK) to see the difference between JSON and JSONP response in your browser.
- Take a look at the  [Chrome Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) in Developer Tools to help compare and troubleshoot with your request/response.

I know this example is very specific but hopefully it helps!

Comment: @Gloopy - Useful info and example jsfiddle very helpful for debugging my code, thanks very much.

Comment: Finally a solution that works! Was running into this problem using smartthings just to drop the keyword here.

Comment: Unfortunately the Youtube service utilized for this example no longer works.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30685729/1014710 shows that it can be done with an Google Developers API key.

Answer (score -3):

If the response data is "pure" JSON, we can just handle it with angular's $http.get.

```
$http.get(url).
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    $scope.responseArray = response.data;
 }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
 });
```

Refer to the example on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp)

Comment: Only if you have CORS set

Comment: this has nothing to do with jsonp at all