# Converting $.ajax call to $http call in angular 404 error

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I'm working on converting a jquery ajax call to an angular $http call, but for some reason am returning a 404 status. Here is the original jquery call.

```
function getStaffInfo(){                    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://my.website.com/j/wkr/stafflist.php',
        data: {f: 'staff'},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'vcLoadStaff',
        success: function(){
                                //alert("success");
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the angular $http call:

```
app.service('staffList', function($http){

var staffList = {};

$http.jsonp('https://my.website.com/j/wkr/stafflist.php', {"f":"staff"})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        staffList = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
});

return staffList;

});
```

Am I missing something in my angular code?

Comment: add {"f":"staff", "callback":"jsonp_callback" } in side params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to append `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to your URL.

```
$http.jsonp('https://my.website.com/j/wkr/stafflist.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {"f":"staff"})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        staffList = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
});
```

**Edit:**  Just to clarify, when you make that change, the resulting data will be wrapped in JSON_CALLBACK([...]).  Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344933/angularjs-jsonp-not-working/16352746#16352746) relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

The http service returns the payload as a promise so you may find you have to call success on the service inside the controller you are using it in like so..

```
app.service('staffList', function ($http) {
    return {
        getList: function () {
            $http.jsonp('https://my.website.com/j/wkr/stafflist.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK', {"f":"staff"})
        }
    };
});

app.controller('staffController', [$scope, staffList, 
    function($scope, staffList) {

        staffList.getList().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(status);
        });
    }
]);
```

The angular $q service may also be useful although I found the above implementation some what easier to use.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

At angular documentation your `$http.jsonp` can be like this:

```
jsonp(url, [config]);
```

So you may try

```
$http.jsonp('https://my.website.com/j/wkr/stafflist.php', {data:{"f":"staff"}})
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp