# $http.get and $http.JSONP failed to get the google api response

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, google-maps

I tried to get api response for "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Canada&sensor=true&region=USA" using angularjs $http .get method and $http.JSONP method. But it doesnt work properly it returns nothing.  When i tried this api via REST client and browser , it provides the JSON data with status code 200.

Here is my code ...
index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<button ng-click="getlocation()">Get Location</button>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function ($scope,$http) {


    $scope.getlocation=function(){

      $scope.method = 'JSONP';
      $http({method: $scope.method, url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Canada&sensor=true&region=USA"}).
        success(function(data, status) {

          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
          alert($scope.data+$scope.status);
      });

    }
}]);
```

while run this code in browser it returns nothing. Throws error.
Could you please help me to get out from this problem??

Comment: mention the error that you are getting

Comment: Status code : 404  Request Failed response... Could you please tell how to call this api "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Canada&sensor=true&region=USA" via angularjs

Answer (score 1):

to work with jsonp in angular, you need... `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` passed to the get call..

e.g.

```
 $http({method: $scope.method, url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Canada&sensor=true&region=USA&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"}).
```

read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344933/angularjs-jsonp-not-working/16352746#16352746)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have tried ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK. But it doesnt work...try this $http({method: $scope.method, url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Canada&sensor=true&region=USA&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"})  in plunker demo :http://plnkr.co/edit/spDiD4V6JCCXrtRNDV11?p=preview ...Once you done this You can understand my issue

Answer (score 0):

The only problem your code has is that there isno such HTTP method as JSONP. In your case you need GET. So use this instead:

```
$scope.method = 'GET';
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/I6qAMbsvLwM3vgZFQa0S?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried  $scope.method = 'GET';
this is also not working showing error as Request failed. this url  http://plnkr.co/edit/I6qAMbsvLwM3vgZFQa0S?p=preview also shows same error "request failed"

Comment: I can see that the demo I provided works perfectly, not sure what fails for you.

Answer (score 0):

> you have to change your request method from **JSONP** to **GET**.

```
 $scope.getlocation=function(){

      $scope.method = 'get';
      $http({method: $scope.method, url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Canada&sensor=true&region=USA"}).
        success(function(data, status) {

          $scope.status = status;
          $scope.data = data;
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
          $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
          $scope.status = status;
          alert($scope.data+$scope.status);
      });

    }
```

I have tested it from my side and its returns

> **Object {results: Array[1], status: "OK"}**

Hope you get what you are looking for.