# angular 1.5 jsonp code call is not hitting the success method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My jsonp code is not working using angular for some reason!  I've read thousands of examples but it simply doesn't work.  See my code below.

I've read this question and it hasn't resolved my problem [Angularjs JSONP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344933/angularjs-jsonp-not-working)

My example code shows the http.jsonp call with the success and error methods defined.  I'm using Chrome to develop and test it with for the moment and the second and third images show the ajax service call and the jsonp response from the service.

**Latest update**

After receiving help from @TheSharpieOne the server response is now returning an actual function (instead of a string which was the problem previously) but the success method is not executed for some reason?

```
    $http.jsonp(url).then(function(response) {
        alert('success');  // not hit
    }, function onError(response) {
        alert('error');  // this is displayed
    });
```

Many thanks,

**Angular JS**

```
var url = serviceRoot + "api/customer/get?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
    alert('success');  // never called
})
.error(function () {
    alert('error');    
});
```

**Chrome network panel**

[Shows chrome network panel, highlighting the ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfSvv.png)

**Ajax response**

[shows ajax response (an array of dates)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo5uN.png)

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: Why are you writing new APIs using JSONP when we have CORS now?

Comment: The console window is empty, no error nothing.  By the way, what's CORS?  Thanks,

Comment: What does the URL look like (query string and all) in the network tab of devtools?

Comment: @Martin — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @TheSharpieOne you can see that in my screen shot named "Shows chrome network panel, highlighting the ajax call"

Comment: Since the $http .success() and .error() will be deprecated, maybe it's a good idea to use the two .then() functions principle. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#http-due-to

Comment: @Martin my bad, links to images :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSONP response is quoted, it shouldn't be. It is supposed execute the script, which will call your callback function. Right now it is just a string, not a JavaScript function call with the parameters.

JSONP works by dropping a new `<script>` tag on the page linking to your URL. When it executes, it is supposed to call your callback. Thus, JSONP's response should be JavaScript and not a string.

Comment: thanks for this, it seems to work now as I've changed the ajax return to not be a string although it doesn't seem reliable? For some reason the success is not always hit. Is there a known issue or am I doing something wrong, I'm using v1.5.0-rc.2. I'm testing with the console window open and the disable cache turned on.  By the way, when complete, the page will have multiple calls to different services using jsonp